# I am working with a SOAP based web service which has been implemented in a RESTful way. What does this exactly mean?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

From what I know, the web service I am working with is using SOAP. That is, it has an envelope, header, body, etc. However, I keep hearing that this particular SOAP service has been implemented in a RESTful way. Another interesting thing that I noticed: When I load the WSDL in SOAP UI, I have to do so by creating a "New REST Project." This goes against my entire understanding of SOAP and REST. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: you sure it not a WADL file? WADL is WSDLfor soap.Rest services can resturn XML it does not need to return JSON. I doubt this is SOAP at all. Probably a REST service returning XML.

Comment: No. Our web services have WSDL files which end in the .wsdl extension. The content of these WSDL files also conform to WSDL norms and start with the following:

`<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://...`

Comment: Then it's a soap service.

Comment: This is a government project and apparently, they are using their own implementation of SOAP from what I have heard... I will have to acquire more details on this.